# Passport Facebook integration issues

Tags: passport.js

So I am having trouble with integrating Facebook into my app.

This is my Facebook auth code :

```html
  passport.use('facebook', new FacebookStrategy({

    clientID: passportConfig.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    clientSecret: passportConfig.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback"

  }, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {

    facebookModel.findOne({'facebook.facebookId' : profile.id}, function(err, user) {

      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }

      if (user) {
        done(null, user);
      }else {
        var facebookUser = new facebookModel();
        facebookUser.facebook.facebookId = profile.id;
        facebookUser.facebook.token = accessToken;
        facebookUser.facebook.name = profile.displayName;
        facebookUser.save(function(error){
          if (error) {
            console.log("Error logging into Facebook.");
          }else {
            done(null, facebookUser);
          }
        });
      }

    });

  }));
```

This is my model :

```html
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
  local : {
    fname : String,
    lname : String,
    username : String,
    email : String,
    password : String
  },
  facebook : {
    facebookId : String,
    token : String,
    name : String
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

However I keep getting an error.

On the back end

- `FacebookUser.facebook.facebookId = profile.id;`
- `TypeError: Cannot set property 'facebookId' of undefined`

However I do see that my profile object has an id.

On the front-end

- `GET http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQB3NfQB7WP ..... net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found what was wrong I was using the wrong model.

Changed from facebookModel to userModel.

Fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`facebookUser.facebook` is undefined
you need declare it, sample :

```
facebookUser.facebook = {}
```